# Interpolate Floats into Url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use the google static map api to render a centerd map view based on a set of longitude and latitude points.

The google map api provides this URL.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.689249,-74.044500&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true

I am trying to use values from my database and inserting them dynamically like this

```
<%= image_tag ('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{@location.latitude},#{@location.longitude}&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true')%>
```

However the resultant image keeps breaking

## Note:

Latitude and Longitude are both float type attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this (with single quotes):

```
'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{@location.latitude},#{@location.longitude}&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true'
```

to this (with double quotes):

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{@location.latitude},#{@location.longitude}&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true"
```

single quotes are interpreted literally, so maybe your interpolation isn't being rendered